# Passing JSON to client side for JS use

Tags: python, json, flask

I am building a POS system and when an order is completed I would like to send some data into Google Analytics.  To attempt to do this I take the last transaction and all of its items from the db using the following code:

```
@app.route('/thankyou')
def thankyou():
    db = get_db()
    summary_cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM orders JOIN order_items USING (transaction_id) WHERE orders.transaction_id = (SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM orders)')
    summary = summary_cursor.fetchall()
    data = map(list, summary)
    print data
    return render_template('thankyou.html', summary = json.dumps(data))
```

My question is how can I assign this data to javascript variables for use with Google Analytics?  I am reading that using Jinja templating in a javascript file is not best practice (I couldn't even get it to work anyways).  Should I be thinking about this problem in an entirely different manner?

Comment: Can you share your Jinja template and elaborate on what result you're hoping for? You certainly shouldn't be using your template in a Javascript file (template rendering is on the server, Javascript execution is on the client). But you can apply Javascript variables inside your template: <script> var x = {{summary["variable"]}}; </script>

Comment: Is this (`<script> var x = {{summary["variable"]}}; </script>`) OK to do in terms of best practice?  I will post my Jinja template in a second.

Comment: Actually, I think I can figure it out if that is acceptable, but I just want to make sure that this is the right way to do it (your solution above).  I don't need any POST or GET requests, right?

Comment: I won't comment on the "best practice" thing, because I'm honestly not sure - I can see why people might be on either side of that argument. But no POST or GET requests will be needed after the initial GET (in which the template gets rendered)